# Obtaining datasource in both JNDI and non-JNDI environment

Tags: java, jndi

I have a modular application with one DAO implementation module that allows interacting with a database through `JDBC`. When I wrote the DAO module, I expected to get my `DataSource` via `JNDI` since the module was used until now as part of a web application. However, I need to use this same DAO module in a standalone application and therefore the datasource can't be obtained via `JNDI`.

Here is how I obtain my datasource:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydatasource");
}
```

I thought about the possibility to define the data source in the upper modules as follows:

For the web app module, same as previous code snippet.

For the standalong module, as follows:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
    dataSource.setUser(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}
```

I'm looking for a better approach if there is one...

Comment: I'd say your approach is just fine. Though I would maybe consider using e.g. HikariCP (https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) over c3p0.

Comment: @Jukka Thanks for HikariCP, I will look at it.